# posting multiple arrays to .net webservice using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

Hello guys I'm struggling posting multiple arrays to a .net web service  here is the signature to my web service.

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function Lib_Processor(ByVal w_vendor As String(), _
                             ByVal w_invoice As String(), _
                             ByVal w_invdate As String(), _
                             ByVal w_amount As Decimal(), _
                             ByVal w_account As String(), _
                             ByVal w_fund As String(), _
                             ByVal w_org As String(), _
                             ByVal w_prog As String(), _
                             ByVal w_adrsstyp As String(), _
                             ByVal w_adrss_seq As String(), _
                             ByVal w_Row As String(), _
                             ByVal w_bank As String(), _
                             ByVal w_user As String(), _
                             ByVal w_addl_info As String()) As List(Of GetErrors)
```

I'm looping a table and getting all the values into objects then using json.stringfy to properly create the object to send to the service.

like this.

```
        var invoice     = JSON.stringify({ w_invoice:w_invoice });
        var vendor      = JSON.stringify({ w_vendor: w_vendor });
        var invdate     = JSON.stringify({ w_invdate:w_invdate });
        var amount      = JSON.stringify({ w_amount:w_amount });
        var fund        = JSON.stringify({ w_fund:w_fund });
        var org         = JSON.stringify({ w_org:w_org });
        var prog        = JSON.stringify({ w_prog: w_prog });
        var account     = JSON.stringify({ w_account: w_account });
        var adrsstyp    = JSON.stringify({ w_adrsstyp:w_adrsstyp });
        var adrss_seq   = JSON.stringify({ w_adrss_seq:w_adrss_seq });
        var Row         = JSON.stringify({ w_Row:w_Row });
        var bank        = JSON.stringify({ w_bank:w_bank });
        var user        = JSON.stringify({ w_user:w_user });
        var addl_info   = JSON.stringify({ w_addl_info: w_addl_info });
```

then i makea call to my service to send in the arrays.

```
$.ajax({

            type: "POST",

            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

            data: '{w_vendor:"' + w_vendor + '",w_invoice:"' + w_invoice + '",w_invdate:"'+w_invdate + "}",
            //data: "{"+vendor, invoice, invdate, amount,account,fund,org,prog,adrsstyp,adrss_seq,Row,bank,user,addl_info +"}",
           // "{"+ vendor+invoice+invdate+amount+account+fund+org+prog+adrsstyp+adrss_seq+Row+bank+user+addl_info+"}"
            url: "ServiceApUtils.asmx/Lib_Processor",

            dataType: "json",

            success: respond,

            error: function (e) { $('.result').html("An Error Occured"); }



        });
```

however this fails miserably i can understand why because im simply trying to send many json objects to the 1 service. how can i fix this? I have tried just doing one object like

```
 var thisInvoice = {INVOICE:INVOICE}
```

and basically

```
       var dto = { 'INVOICE': INVOICE };
       var PnJ = JSON.stringify(dto);
```

but this does not work . how can i properly  adjust this object to be send into my service?
any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please explain why the last example "does not work", what happens?

Comment: Why exactly are you placing json strings inside of json strings? why not just have one json string? This structure doesn't make sense. This is what you're basically generating: `{w_vendor:"{\"w_vendor\":\"somevalue\"}"}` which in of itself is #1 invalid json due to no double quotes around `w_vendor`, and #2 is nested json strings which is most likely not what you want.

Comment: you are right kevin thanks for pointing out my error. can you suggest a solution? i understand that i'm not properly creating the json string but an example would go a long way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after hours of frustruation i decided to do things my own way and here is what i came up with. I have an html table which i read from and i needed to use ajax to send the html data to a webservice. i used jquery to read the table data like the following.

```
/* webservice variables*/
var w_vendor = [];
var w_invoice = [];
var w_invdate = [];
var w_amount = [];
var w_account = [];
var w_fund = [];
var w_org = [];
var w_prog = [];
var w_adrsstyp = [];
var w_adrss_seq = [];
var w_Row = [];
var w_bank = [];
var w_user = [];
var w_addl_info = [];
var w_activity = [];
var w_location = [];
var w_bank = [];
```

then on submit we simply called these functions.

```
function GetAllTableRows() {
    try{

        //var MyInvoice = [];
        $('#ADPControlProcessor_GridView1 tbody tr').each(function (index, value) {
            var row = GetRow(index)
            //MyInvoice.push(row);


        });

        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",

            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

            data: '{' + 'w_vendor:[' + w_vendor + "],w_invoice:[" + w_invoice + "],w_invdate:[" + w_invdate + "]," + "w_amount:[" + w_amount + "],"+
                       "w_account:[" + w_account + "]," + "w_fund:[" + w_fund + "]," + "w_org:[" + w_org + "]," + "w_prog:[" + w_prog + "]," + "w_adrsstyp:[" + w_adrsstyp + "]," +
                       "w_adrss_seq:[" + w_adrss_seq + "]," + "w_Row:[" + w_Row + "]," + "w_bank:[" + w_bank + "]," + "w_user:[" + w_user + "]," + "w_addl_info:[" + w_addl_info+"]" + "}",

            url: "ServiceApUtils.asmx/Lib_Processor",

            dataType: "json",

            success: respond,

            error: function (e) { $('.result').html("An Error Occured"); }



        });




    }
    catch (err)
    {
        alert(err)

    }
    //return MyInvoice;
}
function respond() {

    alert('worked!')

}
function GetRow(rowNum)
{
    try{
        var row = $('#ADPControlProcessor_GridView1 tbody tr').eq(rowNum);


        w_vendor.push('"'+ row.find('td:eq(2)').text().trim()+'"');



        w_invoice.push('"' + row.find('td:eq(1)').text().trim()+'"'   );




        w_invdate.push('"' + row.find('td:eq(3)').text().trim() + '"');


        w_amount.push('"' + row.find('td:eq(4)').text().trim() + '"');

           w_fund.push('"' + row.find('td:eq(5)').text().trim() + '"');


           w_org.push('"' + row.find('td:eq(6)').text().trim() + '"');


           w_account.push('"' + row.find('td:eq(7)').text().trim() + '"');


           w_prog.push('"' + row.find('td:eq(8)').text().trim() + '"');


              w_activity.push('"' + row.find('td:eq(8)').text().trim() + '"');

              w_location.push('"' + row.find('td:eq(8)').text().trim() + '"');


              w_addl_info.push('"' + row.find('td:eq(11)').text().trim() + '"');



    w_adrsstyp.push('"' + row.find('td:eq(12)').text().trim() + '"');


    w_adrss_seq.push('"' + row.find('td:eq(13)').text().trim() + '"');


    w_Row.push('"' + row.find('td:eq(14)').text().trim() + '"');


    w_user.push('"' + "MIGUEL83_BANNER" + '"');

    w_bank.push('"' + "2" + '"');


    }
    catch (err)
    {
        alert (err)
    }

    //return INVOICE;
}
```

The function "GetAllTableRows()"  simply calls the  the rows function to get everysingle row and put the values into the variables. This is code that i actually found on this site.
however i tried to used json stringify but it just would not suite my needs for this particular case if you look at the signature of my service the service expects 12 or 13 string arrays however all the examples i have seen expect you to change your service and create a class and so forth. Well i dont have that ability here so here is the next best thing. how would you do it? you create your own string and thats what i did on the "getRow()" function i concatenated all the strings with double quotes and voila. Then i formatted the string on the data paremeter according to jquery specs and json specs. yes a bit painful but quite useful. In hindsight i could have created a helper function to make format all the strings for me but ill leave that for my future project. hope this helps someone else

Answer (score 0):

Make sure two things:

- Your json string is valid
- Json string name matches with property name on pagemethod

In addition I would suggest you to go through below link which explains how to pass complex type to WebMethod.

http://encosia.com/using-complex-types-to-make-calling-services-less-complex/

Comment: i have already gone through the site and the recommendations would require me to change the web service wich i cant.